# Select all except some rows laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Lets say i have car table and i have 2 columns: model, color.

```
  id      model       color
 ------  --------    ----------
   1      Ford           yellow
   2      Ford           green
   3      Ford           red
   4      Ford           yellow
   5      Subaru         yellow
   6      Subaru         red
```

I don`t want to take where car model ford and color yellow. How can i do it with eloquent. i need this condition.

```
WHERE NOT (model = 'Ford' AND color = 'yellow')
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where('model', '!=', 'ford', 'AND', 'color', '!=', 'yellow')`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `!=` operator.

```
 WHERE (model != 'Ford' AND color != 'yellow')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$products = Modelname::where('model','!=','Ford')->orwhere('color','!=','yellow')->get();

Its same as

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE model != 'Ford' OR color != 'yellow';
```

[image]

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [model] => Ford [color] => green ) 

[1] => Array ( [id] => 0 [model] => Ford [color] => red ) 

[2] => Array ( [id] => 0 [model] => Subaru [color] => yellow ) 

[3] => Array ( [id] => 0 [model] => Subaru [color] => red ) )
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it will not take all yellow color cars, and ford models but i need it when (model=ford and color= yellow)

Comment: You want all yellow and ford ?

Comment: i want get all except id=1 and id=4 on my table. Because its model ford and color yellow

Comment: Try this $products = Modelname::where('model','=','Ford')->orWhere('color','=','yellow')->get(); and let me know

Comment: @Hulk i have update my answer.check it and let me know

Comment: simply i dont need yellow fords, except yellow fords i need get all

Comment: I have attach my answer screenshot

Comment: @Hulk i have update my answer.check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
Select * from car where NOT model = 'ford' AND NOT color = 'yellow'
```

This will Work for You...